# How can I conditionally allow navigation to a user

Tags: angular, testing, service, jasmine, karma-jasmine

So here is my problem, I would like to test this `canActivate` function in my code.

My **AuthRoleGuardService.ts** file:

```js
export class AuthRoleGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const currentUser = this.authService.currentUserSubject.value;

    if (Roles[currentUser.role] >= route.data.role) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/access-denied'], { queryParams: { redirect: state.url }, replaceUrl: true });
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
  it('should allow navigation if user has minimum role', () => {});

  it('should not allow navigation if user does not have minimum role', () => {
    const role = 'DISPLAY';
    const routerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
    expect(roleGuard.canActivate(undefined, ({ url: 'users' } as any) as RouterStateSnapshot)).toBe(false);
    expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['access-denied']);
  });
```

How can I pass the role?

Maybe a good solution:

```js
  it('should not allow navigation if user does not have minimum role', fakeAsync(() => {
    user.role = 'DISPLAY';

    const route = new ActivatedRouteSnapshot();

    route.data = { role: Roles.SHIFTLEAD };

    expect(roleGuard.canActivate(route, mockStateSnapshot)).toBe(false);
    expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/access-denied'], {
      queryParams: { redirect: undefined },
      replaceUrl: true
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

To test a guard you have to do something like this :

```
{ path : "", component : ComponentName, canActivate : [GuardName]}
```

**EDIT**

Case 1 :

```
export class AuthRoleGuardService implements CanActivate {
  test : number = 0 ;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    if (this.test != 0) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate('/access-denied');
    return false;
  }
}
```

For this case the user will stay in the page he is because I can't access to the target page

Case 2 :

```
export class AuthRoleGuardService implements CanActivate {
  test : number = 0 ;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    if (this.test == 0) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate('/access-denied');
    return false;
  }
}
```

For this case the user will go to the target page cause the value of test is equal to '0'

Comment: I know how to use it, and it works correctly. I don't know how to test the service. How can I test that if the role is Display then it should not allow navigation the the users route.

Comment: @szkatalin it will do it automatically, I edit my post to show you with a simple example.